# Sitecore Habitat - GULP is not running sync unicorn task and neither giving any error

Tags: unicorn, gulp, habitat

In Sitecore habitat project, I am running task '05-Sync-Unicorn' in VS task running explorer but it does nothing and just displays "Starting '05-Sync-Unicorn'" in console (even doesn't produce any error in console).

1. What can be the possible reasons?
2. Where can I see GULP tasks log in VS?

Comment: Any errors in your Sitecore log file? Also try going to http://habitat.dev.local/unicorn.aspx and running the sync manually - any errors with that?

Comment: running the sync manually works but doesn't work through gulp task.In sitecore log i cant see any error although there are few warnings. Is there any other log other than sitecore log for gulp tasks?

Comment: Make sure that this /scripts/Unicorn/MicroCHAP.dll isn't blocked by windows (right click on the file, properties, unblock). Also make sure that App_Config/Include/Unicorn/Unicorn.UI.config is in your website and has the <SharedSecret> in it.

Comment: dll in Scripts folder? dll in bin is surely not blocked and everything else you mentioned are in place

Comment: I thought that VS task runner wouldn't do the unicorn because it was ES6. can you open a command prompt at the root of the project and type "gulp 05-Sync-Unicorn" and hit enter. Also are you using the habitat.dev.local for your site url?

Comment: Thanks dnstommy. after running command prompt, I got below message which was not appearing vs task running explorer."Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
message. Do you want to run D:\Habitat\Habitat-master\Habitat-master\scripts\Unicorn\Sync.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"):

Comment: Automated calls are not streaming (nothing is written to the response until everything is complete) and that's why it gives  impression that nothing is happening or sync is not even started

Comment: @dnstommy What do you mean by unblock? I didn't get any option by right click on the file, properties, unblock. Can you please share the screenshot for it?

Comment: @SurendrASharmA It would be like this. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-windows-blocked-access-file Because the file came from the internet, on windows 10, it gets blocked. You get an error until windows is allowed to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I faced similar issue..The task would start and hang up with the below message
Starting '05 Sync Unicorn'..
As mentioned above , along with MicroCHAP.dll, I had to unblock other two files (Sync and Unicorn ) to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and on inspecting my Sitecore log, I found multiple instances of the following error:

> Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path
>   master:/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature. The item does not exist in
>   Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
>   need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?

This fixed worked for me:

- Uninstall Sitecore instance (/habitat.dev.local)
- Reinstall using SIM, ensure you use the exact version listed in the current version of the Habitat installation notes (for me, it was `Sitecore 8.2 Release 1`).
- Install the WFFM module. **Make sure you use the correct version** as listed in the Habitat installation notes (for me, it was `Web Forms For Marketers 8.2 rev 161129`)
- Make sure you complete the WFFM post-install steps (adding to the Web.Config and running SQL scripts).
- Now run `npm install` and `gulp` on your Habitat src folder, as per the habitat installation notes.

Once I resolved the slight mismatch between versions of Sitecore, WFFM and the Habitat source, Unicorn ran fine.